# Prevent large files being uploaded

Tags: java, filter, apache-commons

I use a filter (combined with apache-fileupload) when uploading files to my server, how soon can I determine the size of the file being uploaded?
Is it considered "safe" to rely on the content-length header or could it be missing if the request is chunked?
The underlying problem is that I want to prevent large files being uploaded as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the uploading interface? web, android or desktop?

Comment: Have you set a max size on the file upload handler?

Comment: Sorry for double post. I'm trying to write on my phone: The interface is web. No I haven't set the setSizeMax or setFileSizeMax on the  ServletFileUpload. How could I catch that if a user is trying to send a larger file than I have set on the ServletFileUpload?